# Como contar a frequência de cada letra em uma string?

Tags: java, string

Preciso contar a frequência relativa de cada letra numa string (apenas letras), sem considerar os espaços, sem diferenciar maiúsculas de minúsculas e sem diferenciar letras acentuadas. Eu consegui criar um código que faz mais ou menos isso, mas o programa repete as contagens desnecessariamente. Por exemplo, na frase "Ai minha cuca", o programa imprime "A letra a aparece 3 vezes" três vezes, quando deveria imprimir uma só vez. Como faço para corrigir isso? E faço o programa contar apenas as letras?

**Solucionado!**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
    String S;
    int i, j, cont=0;
    System.out.println("Digite a palavra/frase:");
    // usuário digita string
    S = ent.nextLine();
    // a string é convertida para letras minúsculas
    // para que não haja diferenciação entre 'A' e 'a'
    String s = S.toLowerCase();
    String v = "";
    for (i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
        for (j=0; j<s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i)==s.charAt(j)) {
                cont++;
            } 
        }
        // ao imprimir as frequências, exclui a contagem dos espaços
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' && !v.contains("" + c)) {
            v = v + c;
            System.out.println("A letra "+s.charAt(i)+" aparece "+cont+" vezes.");
        }
        cont=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe que o seu `if` que está dentro do `for` externo, executa uma vez para cada letra da `String`, **não importando se esta letra já foi contada antes ou não**.

Você vai precisar verificar se a letra já foi usada antes ou não. Uma forma de fazer isso é colocar as letras já verificadas em um array, lista ou `StringBuilder` ou `String` e verificar se a letra nova já está lá.

Se você quiser colocar em uma variável `String` (vamos supor que se chame `jaEncontrados`), o seu `if` ficaria assim:

```java
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c != ' ' && !jaEncontrados.contains("" + c)) {
```

EDIT: Coloque o `v = v + s.charAt(j);` dentro do segundo `if`. Vai se transformar em `v = v + c;`.

Comment: Você pode usar o método `contains` da classe `String`, ou então o método `indexOf`.

Comment: Optei por concatenar uma nova string, mas não sei como verificar se a nova letra existe nessa string. Uso outro FOR? Onde devo colocá-lo?

Comment: @CristianeDosSantosCosta Editei a minha resposta. Veja se isso resolve a sua dúvida. :)

Comment: Acho que está quase dando certo... Em qual dos IFs devo colocar sua sugestão? Eu tentei no último (troquei ele pelo seu) e o programa encerra sem imprimir nada.

Comment: @CristianeDosSantosCosta Era no último sim. Aonde você declarou está String, com que valor você a inicializou e como você a está alimentando?

Comment: Alterei o código da pergunta. Veja como ficou.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19036/discussion-between-cristiane-dos-santos-costa-and-victor).

Comment: Não recomento. a maneira correta de fazer isso é com expressão regular

Comment: @DavidSchrammel Eu discordo de ti. Neste caso expressão regular é um canhão para matar uma formiga. É um overkill. Além disso, expressões regulares também têm um desempenho bem inferior a isso. Expressões regulares são boas para reconhecer padrões complexos e fazer substituições com estes padrões, e não para contar as ocorrências. E por fim, isso provavelmente é um exercício de programação acerca de manipulação básica de strings, e portanto expressões regulares estariam fora do contexto da pergunta. Entretanto, se você quiser insistir, poste uma resposta usando expressão regular e vamos ver.

Comment: @VictorStafusa não existe discussão, provavelmente seu código é mais rápido, mas quando colocamos em jogo aspectos como, legibilidade você perde, expressões regulares foram feitas especificamente para resolver problemas com cadeias de caracteres de uma String,ja a sua solução e uma maneira genérica para não dizer gambiarra.

Answer (score -2):

Muito mais fácil:

```
len('Ai minha cuca') - len(replace('Ai minha cuca','a','')
```

Comment: código invalido.

Comment: Como esse código responde o que foi perguntado?

Comment: Luciano ate entendi como o exemplo funciona, mas recomendo que voce oriente a sobre o uso e como ele funciona, alem de adicionar um exemplo mais claro e menos "tosco" por favor. Tirando isto, parece um exemplo pratico mesmo (não testei ainda, mas a logica parece funcional). Note que no java `replace` se usa `String a = "foo"; a.replace('o', 'i');` (ate aonde eu sei ao menos) e pra contar um string usamos `.length()`

Comment: Tem mais um detalhe, o seu codigo da a entender que ira procurar as ocorrencias de uma letra, o que a autora necessita sao as ocorrencias de todos caracteres na string.